# Disable pdf download and save option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have a PDF file being viewed on the browser.

I want to disable Save, Download and print option of the PDF file.

Please help.

Comment: Actually your pdf is already downloaded to user's machine if they can see it.

Comment: wat about using third party app???

Comment: It would be a long trip if you're going to install a third-party app to every visitor's machine. This is not achievable, the only way is never show the file at the first place.

Comment: then what should i do ?? because i dont want users to be able to download the pdf

Comment: Don't upload the pdf?

Comment: You can disable printing of any PDF file using it's security properties. But you cannot prevent users from downloading it. As Teemu notes, if they're viewing it in a browser, by definition they've downloaded it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" 
data="yourpdffile.pdf#toolbar=0" id="pdf_content"><p>Document load was not 
successful.</p></object>
```

Make sure you add **#toolbar=0** in the data attribute after your pdf file.

Comment: It only disables the download button, It doesn't disable save as option and print option on right-click.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iframe` to your own version of PDF viewer.

Use [`pdfJS`](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) and when showing `viewer.html` just remove these buttons.

---

If user is viewing it on it's own tool, than you can't control it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive can disable the PDF functions to download, print and copy as of 2015.

Note however, that users can still print using the browser print function.

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/07/disable-downloading-printing-and.html

[image: I have many e PDFs via a HTML link to the general public which has this functionality.]

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, once the pdf is being viewed by the user, they can save it.

If you are just wanting to obfuscate the download, you could disable the menu as described but to truly prevent downloading of the PDF, then only thing you could really do is a little crazy but not impossible.

You could convert it to images and show those instead. Not an ultimate solution as they would still be able to save each image, but at the very least they would not get a PDF file from it (or at least if they are smart enough to convert the images to one, it would not be the same pdf file or content)

There are many tools to do this and you'd have to implement a viewer with paging but this might achieve what you want.